# Print arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, casting, tostring

I'm writing a method that prints every Object it get passed. This works fine by calling the `Object.toString()` method for the object but doesn't works for arrays. I can find out whether it is an Array with the `Object.getClass().isArray()` method, but I don't know how to cast it.

```
int[] a;
Integer[] b;

Object aObject = a;
Object bObject = b;

// this wouldn't work
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aObject));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bObject));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't know the type you can cast the object to `Object[]` and print it like this (after making sure it is indeed an array and can be cast to `Object[]`). If it is not an instance of `Object[]` then use **reflection** to create an `Object[]` first and then print:

```
private void printAnyArray(Object aObject) {
    if (aObject.getClass().isArray()) {
        if (aObject instanceof Object[]) // can we cast to Object[]
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[]) aObject));
        else {  // we can't cast to Object[] - case of primitive arrays
            int length = Array.getLength(aObject);
            Object[] objArr = new Object[length];
            for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
                objArr[i] =  Array.get(aObject, i);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objArr));
        }
    }
}
```

**TESTING:**

```
printAnyArray(new int[]{1, 4, 9, 16, 25});
printAnyArray(new String[]{"foo", "bar", "baz"});
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
[foo, bar, baz]
```

Comment: How could I find out if it's an primitive array? Also I need to know the primitive type of the array.

Comment: Pls check the updated code, it will **now print any array object** without needing you to cast to every primitive type in an ugly chain of `if/elseif/else`

Comment: Interesting update, though the added expense of reflection and autoboxing is worth mentioning.

Comment: @PaulBellora I have read tons of articles cautioning against using so called "expensive" Reflection but have also seen almost every modern framework making good use of it. Read this for ex: http://buzdin.blogspot.com/2011/01/is-java-reflection-really-slow.html My 2 cents: Make sure you have a good usecase to use reflection and IMHO this question was good fit for that.

Comment: @anubhava - I think we're on the same page; I've also read articles about how the performance of reflection in Java has greatly improved over the years. Just thought it was worth pointing out to the OP. +1 BTW

Comment: This works fine for me because it's used only for debugging where performance isn't that important. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how you can call this method programmatically on any array, it's not going to be possible with primitive arrays. Looking at the docs for the [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class, you'll see there's an overload of `toString()` for every primitive array type.

This is because `int[]` for example extends `Object` rather than `Object[]`.

**EDIT:** here's a regrettably longwinded solution to include primitive arrays:

```
public static void printObject(Object obj) {

    String output;

    if (obj == null) {
        output = "null";
    }
    else if (obj.getClass().isArray()) {

        if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
            output = Arrays.toString((Object[])obj); //Object[] overload
        }
        else if (obj instanceof int[]) {
            output = Arrays.toString((int[])obj);    //int[] overload
        }
        //and so on for every primitive type
    }
    else {
        output = obj.toString();
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

I'm hoping someone else can provide a more elegant solution, but based on the limitations of primitive arrays, this might be the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you let [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) solve your problem? Simply write two (or more) methods with the same name but different signatures and then let the compiler decide which method will be called when the program executes:

```
void print(Object object) {
   System.out.println("Object: " + object);
}

void print(Object[] array) {
    System.out.println("Object[]: " Arrays.toString(array)); 
}

void print(int[] array) {
    System.out.println("int[]: " Arrays.toString(array)); 
}
```

Example usage elsewhere in the code:

```
String first = "test";
print(first);   // prints "Object: test";

String[] second = {"A", "B"};    
print(second);   // prints "Object[]: [A, B]" 

int[] third = {1, 2};
print(third);    // prints "int[]: [1, 2]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection to get to the deeper structure of an Object if you don't want to rely on object's class itself to overload the Object toString method (to get something more useful than printing class name and hash code...)

My suggestion is to use a library that uses reflection to get to the deeper structure, such as GSON: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

```
public static String print(Object object) {
    return new Gson().toJson(object);
}

public static void test() {
    System.out.println(print(new int[][] {new  int[] {1, 2, 3} }));
    // outputs: [[1,2,3]]
    System.out.println(print(new String[] { "aa", "bb", "cc" }));
    // outputs: ["aa","bb","cc"]
}
```

This prints arrays effortlessly, including multi-dimensional arrays and primitive arrays.

But the real benefit is that it prints objects of any class in a uniform way, whether the class has overriden toString in any useful way or not.

Answer (score -2):

If all you want to do is print it out as a String, why cast it? Just treat it as an array of Objects, iterate through the array, and the call the toString() method on each Object.

Comment: But I can't cast it to an `Object` array if it contains primitive types.