# showing array for quickfind

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to print out the full array `id[]` after each time the `union()` method is called. in the `main()` method. also need to bee able to count the number of times the array is accessed. I am aware that it is accessed twice when calling the connected method, once when calling `find()` and up to `2n + 1` when calling `union()`. Please help.

```
    public class QuickFindUF {
private int[] id;    // id[i] = component identifier of i
private int count; // number of components

/**
 * Initializes an empty unionâ€“find data structure with {@code n} sites
 * {@code 0} through {@code n-1}. Each site is initially in its own 
 * component.
 *
 * @param  n the number of sites
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code n < 0}
 */
public QuickFindUF(int n) {
    count = n;
    id = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        id[i] = i;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of components.
 *
 * @return the number of components (between {@code 1} and {@code n})
 */
public int count() {
    return count;
}


/**
 * Returns the component identifier for the component containing site {@code p}.
 *
 * @param  p the integer representing one site
 * @return the component identifier for the component containing site {@code p}
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException unless {@code 0 <= p < n}
 */
public int find(int p) {
    validate(p);

    return id[p];
}

// validate that p is a valid index
private void validate(int p) {
    int n = id.length;
    if (p < 0 || p >= n) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index " + p + " is not between 0 and " + (n-1));
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if the the two sites are in the same component.
 *
 * @param  p the integer representing one site
 * @param  q the integer representing the other site
 * @return {@code true} if the two sites {@code p} and {@code q} are in the same component;
 *         {@code false} otherwise
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException unless
 *         both {@code 0 <= p < n} and {@code 0 <= q < n}
 */
public boolean connected(int p, int q) {
    validate(p);
    validate(q);

    return id[p] == id[q];
}

/**
 * Merges the component containing site {@code p} with the 
 * the component containing site {@code q}.
 *
 * @param  p the integer representing one site
 * @param  q the integer representing the other site
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException unless
 *         both {@code 0 <= p < n} and {@code 0 <= q < n}
 */
public void union(int p, int q) {
    validate(p);
    validate(q);
    int pID = id[p];   // needed for correctness
    int qID = id[q];   // to reduce the number of array accesses

    // p and q are already in the same component
    if (pID == qID)

        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
        if (id[i] == pID) id[i] = qID;
    count--;

}

/**
 * Reads in a sequence of pairs of integers (between 0 and n-1) from standard input, 
 * where each integer represents some site;
 * if the sites are in different components, merge the two components
 * and print the pair to standard output.
 *
 * @param args the command-line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = StdIn.readInt();
    QuickFindUF uf = new QuickFindUF(n);
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        int p = StdIn.readInt();
        int q = StdIn.readInt();

        if (uf.connected(p, q)){
            continue;
        }
        uf.union(p, q);
        StdOut.println(p + " " + q);
    }
    StdOut.println(uf.count() + " components");

}

     }
```

Comment: printing shouldn't be too hard. As for the array-access: you could just wrap the array in a class that does the counting. Alternatively you could calculate the complexity-class (asymptotic, if that's sufficient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to break down your question...

***Part 1:***

> I'm trying to print out the full array id[] after each time the union
>   method is called. in the main method.

try to create a string buffer and add the elements while you access it. once you are done and wanna print the array, you can just print the string buffer..

```
public void union(int p, int q) {
    validate(p);
    validate(q);
    int pID = id[p];   // needed for correctness
    int qID = id[q];   // to reduce the number of array accesses

    // p and q are already in the same component
    if (pID == qID)

        return;

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("");  

    for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
    {
        sb.append(id[i]) + " "; // you are accessing all id elements anyway; add it to the 'sb' string while you are at it
                                // seperate each id element with a space
                                // do it in this place (before the if statement below) if you would like to print the before state of the array

        if (id[i] == pID) 
            id[i] = qID;

        //sb.append(id[i]) + " ";  // do it here if you would like to print the after state of the array

    }

    System.out.println(sb);
    count--;

}
```

***Part 2:***

> also need to bee able to count the number of times the array is
>   accessed. i am aware that it is accessed twice when calling the
>   connected method, once when calling find() and up to 2n + 1 when
>   calling union()

For this you need to consider refactoring your code.. since you are dealing with arrays in the same class, you will not be able to count the number of times you access this array.. You can however consider having the Array in a different class as a private variable. create points of access via a getter and/or setter methods. then you can count the number of times you access the array in a reliable way..

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a general solution for printing an array of primitives in java. You could do it much more simple than this by iterating over the array and printing each member, inserting a newline character once your print loop has completed it's last loop.

```
        int length = Array.getLength(aObject);
        Object[] objArr = new Object[length];
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
            objArr[i] =  Array.get(aObject, i);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objArr))
```

Try a search next time :) 
[Print arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915939/print-arrays-in-java)